# private company

Tags: new-job, negotiation, ethics

If a company says in appointment letter after foreign trips you have to serve 1 year failing to do so you have to pay the actual amount invested on you depending on which month you are leaving. my question is if an employee employed in company more than 2 years still the company can claim if an employee leaving the company after his foreign trip?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there is a misunderstanding here. If I get this correctly, whenever you go on a business trip, and you were to leave 3 months later, you would need to pay the company back for the business trip + those 3 months? It seems rather unclear. Regardless, I do not believe that your company is in their right to have you pay them after you've been on a business trip.

You can see business trips as traveling expenses. Your company should pay for them if they want to invest in you. Giving themselves an insurance saying that you need to pay them back whenever they deploy you in a foreign country for a certain amount of time is ridiculous. (I'd feel sorry for all the military if they had to pay back the government too) Not to mention, what if the company sends you on a trip, and then fires you? would you still need to pay for that trip? Because at that point you would no longer be serving them.

A company is not allowed to "blackmail" you into staying. When a contract ends, you should be allowed to go wherever you want to go without getting a backlash from something like this.

However, I'm not sure whether this is the same in your country. So I would recommend talking to your union or some other independent organization about this. Make sure you formulate your question clearly. Take the questions I asked into account. Once you have confirmation from the union (ask for confirmation on paper), then you can discuss this with that company.

Answer (score 1):

A company can do whatever it likes as long as the contracts it creates aren't illegal or void, but that's a question for a lawyer. Employees leave and sometimes they leave shortly after a conference or a training that they enjoyed on the company time. While this isn't ideal, I feel that it's a business cost that the company should bear, not the employee. However, many managers think differently and include clauses that require employees to repay the cost of trainings or certifications if they leave within X months.

While it's a poor policy, it's perfectly legal for them to demand repayment if you end up leaving. You'll typically be asked to sign a contract or this will be mentioned in your employment agreement. Failure to repay is likely a breach of contract but also damages your reputation. You can either take the training/conference/trip and repay the costs if you end up leaving, or you can elect not to go.

If your manager forces you to go despite your protests and doesn't excuse you from the  repayment *in advance*, you've got a legal minefield as the repayment clause could be void. Asking for exemption from the repayment before taking the trip is a reasonable thing to ask for, as anything can happen in a year. Managers aren't always as reasonable as they should be however so proceed with caution. They could fire you for refusing to take the trip.